# Creating a Variable From Two Others

Tags: php

In the HTML table below, I would like to add a third column that equals $row["countSubmissions"] times 10 plus $row["countComments"].  How could I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT 
    l.loginid, 
    l.username, 
    COALESCE(s.total, 0) AS countSubmissions, 
    COALESCE(c.total, 0) AS countComments
FROM login l    
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT loginid, COUNT(1) AS total 
    FROM submission 
    GROUP BY loginid
) s ON l.loginid = s.loginid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT loginid, COUNT(1) AS total 
    FROM comment 
    GROUP BY loginid
) c ON l.loginid = c.loginid
GROUP BY l.loginid
ORDER BY countSubmissions DESC 
LIMIT 10";

  $result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

$arr = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec1edit\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename1edit1"><a href="http://www...com/.../members/index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.stripslashes($row["username"]).'</a></td>';
    echo '<td class="sitename1edit2">'.stripslashes($row["countSubmissions"]).'</td>';
    echo '<td class="sitename1edit2">'.stripslashes($row["countComments"]).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: stripslashes() shouldn't be used here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the SQL to include the extra column:

```
SELECT 
    l.loginid, 
    l.username, 
    COALESCE(s.total, 0) AS countSubmissions, 
    COALESCE(c.total, 0) AS countComments,
    COALESCE(s.total, 0) * 10 + COALESCE(c.total, 0) AS totalScore
...
```

or do the calculation in PHP:

```
echo '<td class="sitename1edit2">'. $row['countSubmissions'] . '</td>';
echo '<td class="sitename1edit2">'. $row['countComments'] . '</td>';
echo '<td class="sitename1edit2">'. ($row['countSubmissions'] * 10 + row['countComments']) . '</td>';
```

I don't think the calls to [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) are necessary so I removed them.

Answer (score 0):

after

```
echo '<td class="sitename1edit2">'.stripslashes($row["countComments"]).'</td>';
```

add the following

```
echo '<td>' . ($row["countSubmissions"] * 10 + $row["countComments"]) . '</td>';
```